# Video Compression in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression

I want to compress and decompress a video File in Android.I tried with zipping and unzipping it and it was successful :)

But what I need is compress and decompress it like how it happens in Watsapp. Also, zipping could only compress the video by 2.5% .

I also tried looking for FFmpeg in android, but I was not able to get though it

Could anyone provide and good reference/help/CODE EXAMPLE where a .mp4 file could be easily compressed ?

Thanks !!

Comment: You have any guess how watsapp do it?

Comment: no I don't have any idea regarding that :|

Comment: yeah . Whatsapp does that very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Whats app does it using MediaCodec. It doesnt do as quickly as it looks. The preview is a calculated preview which is shown to user. The actual compression takes place while sending. Try compressing 200 Mb file and see the file size in videos/sent folder. You will get an idea when and how much time it takes to compress.